# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'logpo' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

i am trying to use spring validation using annotation.But when am running the application,it gives following exception-

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/SpringTest] threw 
exception [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target     
object for bean name 'logpo' available as request attribute] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean    
 name 'logpo' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:408)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:140)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(index_jsp.java:196)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:98)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

i have tried ,but not able to solve this .
index.jsp
In this page there is two fields for username and password.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="login.do" commandName="logpo" method="GET">
Enter name :
<form:input path="uname"  />
<form:errors path="uname" /><br>
Enter pass :
< form:input path="password"/>
<form:errors path="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="In" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID"
version="2.5"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" >

<display-name>SpringTest</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-
class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
  <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

dispacher-servel.xml

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<!--    Dispacher -->
<bean
    id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property
        name="prefix"
        value="" />

    <property
        name="suffix"
        value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
</bean>



</beans>
```

and controller is
LoginController.java

```
 package com.controller;

 import java.util.Iterator;
 import java.util.List;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.validation.Valid;

 import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
 import org.hibernate.Query;
 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
 import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 import com.util.HibernateUtil;
 import com.util.LoginPojo;

 @Controller
 public class LoginController {
private static final Logger logger = Logger
        .getLogger(LoginController.class);
private LoginPojo llogin;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView loginAuth(@Valid LoginPojo logpo ,BindingResult     
  br,HttpServletRequest req,ModelAndView mav) {
    logger.info("loginAuth method");
    //ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    if(br.hasErrors()){
         mav.setViewName("index");
    }else{
                    mav.setViewName("success");
  }
```

and i have added all required jar .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're invoking the index.jsp directly, without going through a Spring controller that initializes the `logpo` bean and sets it in the model.

Don't do that. Always go through a controller. The view needs the `logpo` bean, that must be created by the controller.

Comment: By letting Spring instantiate it and adding it to the model, just like you're doing in your loginAuth method, or by doing `modelAndView.addObject("logpo", new LoginPojo())`.